# Biblatex related entry: clearfield

Tags: biblatex

In the bibliography of an article I have to suppress the "series" field, and I use `\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}`. It works as expected. However, in the related entries the series is printed anyway. What I am missing? This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{Norberg:Introduction-fr,
  address = {Stockholm},
  author = {Norberg, Dag},
  publisher = {Almqvist \& Wiksell},
  title = {{I}ntroduction a l'étude de la versification latine médiévale},
  year = {1958},
  series = {Acta Universitatis Stockolmiensis. Studia Latina Stockholmiensia
    5},
  langid = {french},
   }
@BOOK{Norberg:Introduction-en,
  address = {Washington, D.C.},
  author = {Norberg, Dag},
  editor = {Ziolkowski, Jan M.},
  publisher = {Catholic University of America Press},
  title = {{A}n introduction to the study of {M}edieval {L}atin versification},
  year = {2004},
  related = {Norberg:Introduction-fr},
  relatedtype = {translationof},
  series = {Medieval Culture},
  langid = {american},
  translator = {Roti, Grant C. and de La Chapelle Skubly, Jacqueline}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authortitle,backend=biber,autocite=plain]{biblatex}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{series}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
See \autocite[44]{Norberg:Introduction-en}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

If I cite the original text, not the translation, the `series` field is not printed.
[image: Output of MWE]

Thanks you for your kind attention.
guido, Italy

Comment: Generally speaking it is more effective to remove a field with a sourcemap. `\clearfield` often works well enough, but there are edge cases like this one that pop up from time to time and that are tricky to get right, so that's why I always recommend a sourcemap to get rid of a field.

Comment: Your suggestion is brilliant and works perfectly, thank you. I had never used `\DeclareSourcemap` before, but if I understand correctly this command works at a deeper level in comparison with `\clearfield`. It is interesting that e.g. a similar command with `translator` (`\clearname`) works also with related entries. Perhaps a clarification in the biblatex manual might be useful. Thanks a lot, my publisher will be grateful too...